# How can I get the current username from a script run with pkexec?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I'm executing a python script as root with `pkexec` and I'm using `working_dir = os.getenv('HOME')` to get the username but it always returns root instead of test1 which is the current user.

How can I get the user that ran `pkexec` instead?

Script is located in /usr/bin if that information is any use.

Comment: `root` is a user. "Executing as root" means "running as the user `root`". It does not mean "running as the user test1 but with extra privileges". If the process ran as root through suid, use `getuid`. If it ran through sudo, use `SUDO_USER`. If it ran through su, try the parent processes. If it ran through cron, there are no other users involved.

Comment: I've used it as suggested by the proposed answer but I'm not sure if it works under python 2.7. It's running through pkexec

Comment: [Apparently `pkexec` sets a `PKEXEC_UID`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html)

Comment: I tried getting it with `pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name` but it still returns root. I'm not sure how to get the pkexec_uid

Comment: `PKEXEC_UID` is an environment variable. Use `os.environ["PKEXEC_UID"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to that other guy, in the end, below is what I did to get the current user:

```
import os
import pwd

user = pwd.getpwuid(int(os.environ["PKEXEC_UID"])).pw_name
working_dir = '/home/' + user
```

Answer (score 4):

[The `sudo` man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.18/sudo.man.html) describes the environment variables which hold the information of the user who invoked it.

```
import os
print os.environ["SUDO_USER"]
```

Comment: will that work in python 2.7? I'm having trouble getting it to work ` File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SUDO_USER'`

Comment: What if i'm using pkexec?

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a pure bash solution, this finds the user run with sudo or pkexec:

```
if test -z "$SUDO_USER"
then
    USER=$(getent passwd $PKEXEC_UID | cut -d: -f1)
else
    USER=$SUDO_USER
fi
```